# Method dispatch with missing arguments

Tags: r, arguments, r-s4, optional-arguments, method-dispatch

How can I avoid the classic `Error: argument "<argname>" is missing, with no default` error (see example below) when **explicitly** dispatching argument values to subsequent S4 methods in a given S4 method.

---

## Example

### Big picture

- Whe have a method `foo()` that calls method `bar()`.
- Both methods depend on arguments `x` and `y`.
- Method `foo()` dispatches arguments `x` and `y` to `bar()` in an **explicit** way: `bar(x=x, y=y)`.

Now, the crucial point here is that I don't want `foo()` to care if any or all of the arguments that are passed along to `bar()` are missing.

### Generic methods

```
setGeneric(
    name="foo",
    signature=c("x", "y"),
    def=function(x, y, ...) {
        standardGeneric("foo")
    }
)
setGeneric(
    name="bar",
    signature=c("x", "y"),
    def=function(x, y, ...) {
        standardGeneric("bar")
    }
)
```

### Methods for `bar()`

```
setMethod(
    f="bar", 
    signature=signature(x="missing", y="missing"), 
    definition=function(x, y, ...) {
        print("Doing what I'm supposed to do when both args are missing")
        return(NULL)
    }
)
setMethod(
    f="bar", 
    signature=signature(x="ANY", y="missing"), 
    definition=function(x, y, ...) {
        message("'y' is missing, but I can give you 'x':")
        print(x)
        return(NULL)
    }
)
setMethod(
    f="bar", 
    signature=signature(x="missing", y="ANY"), 
    definition=function(x, y, ...) {
        message("'x' is missing, but I can give you 'y':")
        print(y)
        return(NULL)
    }
)
setMethod(
    f="bar", 
    signature=signature(x="ANY", y="ANY"), 
    definition=function(x, y, ...) {
        message("x:")
        print(x)
        message("y:")
        print(y)
        return(NULL)
    }
)
```

### Method for `foo()`

As mentioned above, I don't want `foo()` to care if any or all of the arguments that are passed along to `bar()` are missing. It is just supposed to pass everything along to `bar()` in an explicit manner:

```
setMethod(
    f="foo", 
    signature=signature(x="ANY", y="ANY"), 
    definition=function(x, y, ...) {
        bar(x=x, y=y)    
    }
)
```

The method def might look good on first sight, but it will fail if either `x` or `y` are missing when calling it:

```
> foo(x="Hello", y="World!")
x:
[1] "Hello"
y:
[1] "World!"
NULL
> foo(x="Hello")
Error in bar(x = x, y = y) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'y' in selecting a method for function 'bar': Error: argument "y" is missing, with no default
> foo()
Error in bar(x = x, y = y) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'bar': Error: argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

### Workaround

This is the only workaround that I could come up with so far:

```
setMethod(
    f="foo", 
    signature=signature(x="ANY", y="ANY"), 
    definition=function(x, y, ...) {
        if (missing(x) && missing(y)) {
            bar()    
        } else if (missing(x)) {
            bar(y=y)
        } else if (missing(y)) {
            bar(x=x)
        } else {
            bar(x=x, y=y)
        }
    }
)

> foo(x="Hello", y="World!")
x:
[1] "Hello"
y:
[1] "World!"
NULL
> foo(x="Hello")
'y' is missing, but I can give you 'x':
[1] "Hello"
NULL
> foo(y="World!")
'x' is missing, but I can give you 'y':
[1] "World!"
NULL
> foo()
[1] "Doing what I'm supposed to do when both args are missing"
NULL
```

It works, but I don't really like it because of all the `if ... else` statements. The whole "if-else logic" already went in the specification of the various methods for `bar()`. After all, that's the whole point of having a method dispatcher in the first place, right? Hence I would consider the statements as "undesired work" and I'm looking for a better way.

One could of course resort to to using `NULL` as default value for all "critical" arguments, but I would like to rely on `missing()` instead of `is.null()` in my functions as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative idea. (It's broadly inspired by the sort of "computing on the language" used by many of R's model-fitting functions.)

```
setMethod(
    f="foo", 
    signature=signature(x="ANY", y="ANY"), 
    definition=function(x, y, ...) {
        mc <- match.call()
        mc[[1]] <- quote(bar)
        eval(mc)
    }
)


foo(x="Hello")
# 'y' is missing, but I can give you 'x':
# [1] "Hello"
# NULL

foo(y="World")
# 'x' is missing, but I can give you 'y':
# [1] "World"
# NULL

foo()
# [1] "Doing what I'm supposed to do when both args are missing"
# NULL
```

Comment: That is so awesome!! Exactly the missing puzzle piece that I was looking for! I did experiment with `selectMethod()`, but that's only like doing the dispatching work manually. But `match.call()` puts it all back to "auto-select-mode", so nice! Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: @Rappster Yeah, it's pretty sweet. If you need to perform some even more involved manipulations of the call and its arguments, definitely take a look at the function def of `lm` for further inspiration.

Comment: I think this sort of call manipulation is generally best avoided, but I can't see a better solution here.

Comment: @hadley Basically agreed. I feel like that call manipulation *shouldn't* be required and suspect that it *isn't*, but still haven't figured out what the correct incantation really *is*.

Comment: Or this might be a bug in S4 dispatch.